# ORA-06575: Package or function F is in an invalid state

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  f
return integer
AS;
BEGIN 
  return (select count(*) from exemplo); 
END ;

select f() from dual;
```

When I execute the funtion give me this error:

```
ORA-06575: Package or function F is in an invalid state
```

Comment: Why do you have a semicolon after `AS` ? After you compile the function it will tell you there are errors; use `show errors` or query the `user_errors` view to see what is actually wrong.

Comment: with or without they ddon't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you compile the function your client will say something like:

```
Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
```

or

```
Function F compiled

Errors: check compiler log
```

If you're using SQL*Plus or SQL Developer (and maybe other client, but they may have their own equivalent) you can then do `show errors` to see what is wrong:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
3/3      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
         begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
         exists prior external language
```

or you can query the `user_errors` view to see the same information.

Removing the semicolon after the `AS` then reports:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
5/11     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
         ( - + case mod new not null <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable>
         continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev
         sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval
         date <a string literal with character set specification>
         <a number> <a single-quoted SQL string> pipe
         <an alternatively-quoted string literal with character set specification>
         <an alternat
5/39     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:
         . , @ ; for <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> group having intersect
         minus order partition start subpartition union where connect
         sample
```

You can't return a query result directly. You need a local variable to select *into*, and which you then return; something like:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  f
return integer
AS
  l_count pls_integer;
BEGIN 
  select count(*) into l_count from exemplo;
  return l_count; 
END ;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `alter session set nls_language = 'English';` in order to get error message in english.

Function must be like this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  f return integer AS
   ret INTEGER;
BEGIN 
   select count(*) INTO ret from exemplo; 
   return ret;
END;
```